# Error logged: ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

Hi my ultimate goal is to tag the selected mails with general label but I am getting this below error while executing the Gmail chrome extension.

> Error logged: ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined

The code in which I used the GmailApp is posted below. Please check it.

tag.js:

```
function whenNoneSelected(route) {
  return false;
}
InboxSDK.load('1', 'sdk_mailtag_fd47af3e65').then(function(sdk) {
  function tagLabel() {
alertify.success('Threads marked as General'); 
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("General");
var threads = GmailApp.getThreads(); //var threads = label.getThreads(); 
for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
//add label "General" for selected threads
threads[i].addLabel(label);
}    
  }
  sdk.Toolbars.registerToolbarButtonForList({
    title: 'General',
    section: sdk.Toolbars.SectionNames.INBOX_STATE,
    iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL('/icons/tag.png'),
    onClick: tagLabel,
    hasDropdown: false,
    hideFor: whenNoneSelected,
    keyboardShortcutHandle: null
  });
});
```

Anyone with relevant solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please show us where you are defining it as well

Comment: server-side apps script will never run as client-side chrome extension code.

Comment: @Irtza I am using GmailApp only in 7th and 8th line of this tag.js file above.

Comment: Yes you are using it here, but look at the error. GmailApp is not defined. Which means that either you've not initialized it like `GmailApp = ....` or its been initialized in a smaller scope which is outside the scope of this code. S look at where you're defining it, or including it if it is an external file.

Answer (score 1):

GmailApp is used within a Google Apps Script project.  If you're writing an extension, you'll need to use the Gmail API.